# JQuery delete DOM element after fading out

Tags: jquery, dom, fadeout

I want to delete an DOM element right after fading out. What I did so far is

```
$(element).click(function()
{
    $(this).fadeOut(500, function() { $().remove(this); });
});
```

But now I always get this error in Firebug: http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/5912/Jing/2009-02-04_1109.png

I guess it is because the fadeOut function is not really done when the callback gets called. And I can not put the `$.remove()` part after the fadeOut call because otherwise it gets removed instantly.

So do you know of any way I can do this better?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You're using the [`remove()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/remove) function wrongly.

```
$(element).click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(500, function() { $(this).remove(); });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

why messing here just use
$('#anydiv').remove();

Comment: I guess he wants to fadeout first and remove the element after the fading is finished.

Answer (score 0):

or $.remove($(this));