# jQuery highlight effect before remove()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Consider the following snippet:

```
$('.remove_item').click(function(e) {
    var _item = $(this).closest('.cart_item');
    if(confirm('Biztosan törölhetem a terméket a kosárból?')) {
        _item.effect('highlight', {}, 100).stop().fadeOut('fast');
        _item.remove();
...
```

I'd like to highlight the actual row before trashing (`.remove()`) it. If i don't `.remove()` the item, highlight working.

How can i highlight first, then remove element?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510761/jquery-delete-dom-element-after-fading-out

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the callback functionality of `effect` and `fadeOut` to do actions when the first action has finished:

```
_item.effect('highlight', {}, 100, function(){
    $(this).fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

This says "highlight `_item`. When this is finished, fade it out. When this is finished, remove it."

Comment: You don't need the callback to `.effect()`. The `.fadeOut()` will be automatically queued to run after `.effect()`.

Comment: @patrick Thanks for the clarification -- I get confused sometimes by the jQuery queue...

Answer (score 5):

Yo ushould be able to assign a callback on the fadeOut:

```
$('.remove_item').click(function(){
    if(confirm('Biztosan törölhetem a terméket a kosárból?'))
    {
         $(this).closest('.cart_item').fadeOut(500, function() { $(this).remove(); });
    }
});
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to queue the .remove()

```
_item.queue( function() { $(this).remove(); });
```